# Using VNC to deliver a subscription based application

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services

I'm developing an application with Vue and Flask and trying to figure out how to make this deliverable. The use will be healthcare related and I am considering AWS Lightsail to easily spin up virtual machines for each user to keep data and data management separate and customizable. The idea is that I would package the application as an electron app which runs on an Ubuntu or Windows machine, and users remote into it to utilize the application. Of course, I understand there are limitations like the number of simultaneous connections. I've also considered using a containerized application, but haven't learned enough about them yet.

Especially to remain HIPAA compliant, I figured this would be the simplest, and would be similar to running an application locally on a machine except that users wouldn't have to worry about configuring a machine to do it.

This may or may not be possible, but after a bit of internet research, I couldn't find enough information to confirm that this is plausible and would really appreciate your input.

Thanks

Comment: What is VNC? Are you talking about remote desktops? If so, many VNC clients and servers limit passwords to 8 characters usually with silent truncation. See, for example, [Using longer password than 8 characters with VNC?](https://superuser.com/q/1006256/173513) Regarding your security architecture, you should probably work with a consultant to help with the design and architecture. There is too much to discuss in Stack Overflow questions and comments. Also see Peter Gutmann's *[Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf)*.

Comment: Yes, by VNC I meant remote desktop access like windows remote desktop, or the linux equivalent. We will be using encrypted windows machines in our office to run the application, but I was wondering if this is something that could easily be scaled for more users. And thanks, I plan to talk to a security consulting soon and will check out that book!